# Odds of pulling three cards in a certain order

Tags: probability

Can one of you math this for me?

You've got a deck of 88 cards. Let's call the first card "1", the next "2", and so on.

What are the odds of pulling "1", "2", and "3" out of the deck, in that order?

Comment: Let's try something easier: What's the odd of getting a specific card, say 1, out of a deck of 88 cards?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new using this website, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

It should be 1/88 * 1/87 * 1/86 = 1/(88*87*86) = 1/658416 Or about 1.52*10^-6.

My thought is that you have exactly one card in 88 that is the desired result of 1.  With that card drawn, the deck has  87 remaining, again only one card is the 2. The same logic follows for the 3.

Because probability is the result of dividing the outcome by the population, and multiple probabilities are multiplied to determine the overall probability, I used the equation above.

A simple example: what are the chances I draw one card from a deck of four unique cards? 1/4 or 0.25 or 25%.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "what are the odds that the first card drawn is $1$, the second card drawn is $2$, and the third card drawn is $3$?": There are $88!$ different possible shuffles of the deck of $88$ cards. There are "only" $(88-3)!$ shuffles that have the first three cards being $1,2,3$ in that order. So the probability is $\frac{85!}{88!} = \frac{1}{88\cdot 87\cdot 86}$.

If you mean "what are the odds that $1$ is drawn before either $2$ or $3$, and also $2$ is drawn before $3$?", then that is $\frac{1}{6}$.